# how to tell browser then recognize my stylesheet first then the framework i use?

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

I use blueprint and browser recognize them first and not mine if they have something.

how i can do something then browser recognize the style-sheet of mine first then they try to use them in page.

i know i can use !important but it's not good that i put !important on every tag. are their any hack to apply my stylesheet first even blueprint have some for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using stylesheets in the opposite order of what you want.  If you want your styles to be in effect instead of the styles from the frameworks you are using, list your stylesheets **after** the other stylesheets.  Ideally, your stylesheets will be listed last.  That's the effect of *cascading* for stylesheet rules.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets are applied in order of appearance, just insert your css after those of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have specificity rules that determine which style is applied. If you have multiple external stylesheets, the easiest way to ensure that your desired styles are applied is to load your stylesheet after the Blueprint stylesheet. Any style rules defined in your stylesheet will override the Blueprint styles.